# Is there a good way to do "partial broadcast" in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I have the following sequence of calculations

```
origvals     = [3, 9, 2, 8, 5, 9, 1, 6, 3, 2]
updates      = [2, 5, 9, 8]
indices      = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
updates_pb   = [2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9] # tf.gather(updates, indices)
result       = origvals + updates_pb
```

Here I've shown updates_pb as a sort of piecewise broadcast of the values '2', '5', and '9', based on the updates values and the indices.  In my use case, almost always, the indices vector will have long runs of repeated values.

Is there a more efficient way to compute the final result value than through the intermediate construction of the highly repetitious updates_pb tensor?  A wish-list function might be:

```
result = tf.gather_add(origvals, updates, indices)
```

Comment: I think tf.gather followed by + is the best way to accomplish what you want.